# Create new triplets based on a query result

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, ontology

[![enter image description here][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AG7MM.png

Given the following triple

I would like to get a result
**:crr1 :hasPart :part1
:crr2 :hasPart :part3**

I have tried currently a query below but I don't get the expected results I am trying to put a filter FILTER (?part = ?part2) over the UNION of two queries but failed to get the response I need, what am I doing wrong here?

My sole purpose with the query is to find the missing connections like in this case if CRR1 and CRR2 are connected via Part2 I would then like to create a new CRR that connects Part1 and Part3 depending upon who is the DOB in this example it is CRR1

```
:crr1 a :XObject .
:crr2 a :XObject .
:crr3 a :XObject .
:crr4 a :XObject .

:part1 a :Part
:part2 a :Part
:part3 a :Part
:part4 a :Part
:part5 a :Part

:crr1 :hasPart :part1 .
:crr1 :hasPart :part2 .
:crr2 :hasPart :part2 .
:crr2 :hasPart :part3 .
:crr3 :hasPart :part3 .
:crr3 :hasPart :part4 .
:crr4 :hasPart :part4 .
:crr4 :hasPart :part5 .

:crr1 :hasType :DOB .



PREFIX : <http://example.com/test#> 
construct {

?o :hasPart ?part .
:crr2 :hasPart ?part2 .
}
where
{
    {
  ?o :hasPart ?part
  {
    select DISTINCT ?o
      where {
      :crr2 (:hasPart/^:hasPart)+ ?o
      FILTER (:crr2 != ?o)
      }
  }
  FILTER EXISTS {?o :hasType :DOB .}
    }
    UNION
    {
        :crr2 :hasPart ?part2 .
    }
 FILTER (?part = ?part2)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question properly, but let me try to answer it.

If you are looking to construct a triple between :crr1 and :part3, as the 
 3rd paragraph of your questions suggests, then you need something like this:

```
PREFIX : <http://example.com/test#>

CONSTRUCT {?dob :hasPart ?part}
WHERE {
?dob :hasType :DOB .
?dob :hasPart ?p .
?otherCRR :hasPart ?p.
FILTER(?dob != ?otherCRR)
#The above establishes whether the DOB CRR and another one are connected via any part
?otherCRR :hasPart ?part .
FILTER NOT EXISTS {?dob :hasPart ?part}
#This instead makes sure that there isn't already a connection between the DOB and the part in question.
}
```

If instead you are looking for the parts of :crr2 that are not shared with any other CRR where some connection exists and the other CRR is a DOB, as the 1st paragraph of your question seems to suggest, then you need something like this:

```
PREFIX : <http://example.com/test#>

CONSTRUCT {
?o :hasPart ?part .
:crr2 :hasPart ?part2 .
}
WHERE{
?o :hasPart ?sharedPart, ?part .
?o :hasType :DOB .
FILTER(?sharedPart != ?part)
:crr2 :hasPart ?sharedPart, ?part2 .
FILTER NOT EXISTS {?o :hasPart ?part2}
FILTER NOT EXISTS {:crr2 :hasPart ?part}
}
```

This returns the triples you are after.
Notice that in your filter, you say that ?part and ?part2 must be the same, so you can't have them as :part1 and :part3, respectively, in your returned triples.

It may also interest you that you can insert your triples directly into the graph with an insert query. Just replace CONSTRUCT with INSERT.

Comment: I am sorry may be I wasnt clear in writing the usecase correctly, But let me try another hand on this the usecase is

Comment: Supposed there is a CRR1 that has 2 parts part 1 and part2 and I have another CRR2 that has part2 and Part3 and CRR3 has part 3 and Part 4 and here in this case lest consider CRR1 as DOB so now I need to create a VCRR that would connect Part1 and Part3 and Part1 and Part4 also

Comment: I am still not very clear, sorry.
Do you want to create a new CRR altogether?
If so, I tend to use something like this: BIND(IRI(CONCAT(STR(?CRR),"_somestring")) AS ?newCRR)

Comment: Yes correct I have added an image to the question so here is the green bubble that I call virtual crr that I need to create given a particular crr I need to find all its parts and connect the ones that do not exist

Comment: I see, so you want a virtual crr between any two parts that are not already connected?
Where does the DOB come into this though?

Comment: Try something like this then, which will create 12 new triples:
the virtual CRR between (1,5);(1,4);(1,3);(2,5);(2,4);(3,5).

INSERT {?virtualCrr :hasPart ?part1 , ?part2}
WHERE {
?part1 a :Part .
?part2 a :Part .
FILTER(?part1 < ?part2)

FILTER NOT EXISTS {
?realCrr :hasPart ?part1 , ?part2 ;
         a :XObject .
FILTER(?part1 < ?part2)}
BIND(IRI(
CONCAT("http://example.com/test#virtualCRR",
STRAFTER(STR(?part1),'#'),
"_",
STRAFTER(STR(?part2),'#'), "_"))
AS ?virtualCrr)}

Comment: If the above works, can you let me know so I can edit my answer?

Comment: so the DOB means the owner of the part so the owner needs to know who all are these parts being shared with later in the tree so the CRR combines 2 parts from 2 companies which are called differently in company 1 is called part1 and company 2 its called part2 and if the same part is propagated by company 2 to company 3 and so on...then company 1 needs to know where all its parts are being sent and that is where a virtual crr is needed

Comment: so the query would go like user will send in a random crr and then we need to find what parts does it share with other crrs and build the missing realtions